# WPS Office Writer Automatic Color problem

Tags: wps-office

I used WPS Writer on Ubuntu 14 with automatic color and it was black. All my docs was saved with auto color. :(

Trusty is almost dead, so I recently installed the new Ubuntu 20, reinstalled WPS and now I can't see my docs text because the automatic color is very, very light grey.

I changed the default font and color in the settings but it not affected for the automatic color, that is still grey. So, when I open an old document saved with auto color, the text cannot be readable. I know if I select all the text and change the color to black will show up the content but...

My question is: How to change back the automatic color to black?

Thanks for any advice!

Screenshot attached — the automatic color is grey, not black:

[image: The automatic color is grey not black]

Answer (score 0):

This colour overlay is called Eye Protection Mode. Toggle it in the view menu. It is a nuisance rather than a feature.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).